# Can't execute the function in the newly added DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I want to present the data I've received from a web socket server as buttons that represent options. Each of these options (buttons) contains an event `on:click` that will fire and execute the function after it is clicked. These buttons load after I send a message to the web socket server, the text value of each button will be sent later as a response.

The buttons are added and the style is performed after I added a `:global` modifier. But, the buttons can't execute the function after I clicked on them.

I go to the inspector in the browser, and the button shows the following:

```html
<button type="button" on:click="{" check="" }="">
   Portuguese
</button>
```

This is the DOM I'm adding in the script tag of my Svelte component:

```html
message = `
   <div class = "message-item received">
      <button type = "button" class = "bot-text" on:click = { send_answer }>
          ${data.message.bot_text}
      </button>
   </div>
`;

roomContent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', message);
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Why not? This simply is not how Svelte can or should be used.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But, it is the only way I have now to call a function within newly added buttons that do not exist in the component.

Comment: I tried to create a new div to place in those newly added buttons, but it doesn't meet my app requirements.

Comment: Then you should ask about help with that, because this will be going nowhere. Adding dynamic DOM is basic in principle: A list of data + `{#each}`. If you still have trouble with that, show what you tried and what you need.

Comment: This part of the code is a wrong syntax and I can’t understand it ‘ <button type="button" on:click="{" check="" }="">’

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi That is what ends up in the browser, because the OP tried to inject Svelte syntax as HTML.

Comment: @H.B. tnx I got it.

Comment: @lrikio so what do you pass to the send_answer?

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi Yes, this shows up when I inspect the page. The `send_answer()` is simple at the moment just to test first:
`function send_answer() { console.log('clicked') }`

Comment: @CyrusRaoufi Later, I want to get the text value of the button and pass it as an answer to the web socket server after I clicked on it.

Comment: Is it possible to prevent the OP to inject the Svelte syntax as HTML?

Comment: I added the $ sign and I got the following:
`<button type="button" on:click="function" send_answer()="" {="" console.log('clicked');="" }=""> Portuguese </button>`

Comment: *"But, it is the only way I have now to call a function within newly added buttons that do not exist in the component"* The problem is not how you call the function, but how you create the buttons... The button element must be in the Html part - wrapped inside an `{#if}`, `{#each}` or `{#await}` block depending on your logic.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of the question linked before.  The problem is caused by the OP doing direct DOM manipulation instead of using a state based approach as should be done in Svelte.  This is what makes Svelte being a compiler different from other frameworks that are 'mere libraries'.

Comment: @Corrl Thank you for your recommendation. I thought of adding two divs, one to put in the messages I receive from the web socket server (that can be text or represented as buttons in html), and the other one for user inputs. But, the div that contains the chat content gets messy and the user messages submitted before the server responses even I added `roomContent.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', message); `

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Yes, but this one is a little bit detailed. Thank you, you are right. This is exactly what has been mentioned before. So, is it possible to keep the same logic and prevent the OP from doing direct DOM manipulation?

Comment: Simply avoid `.insertAdjacentHTML()` and create the buttons based on the data you  receive from the websocket using the mentioned elements. This might be answered more precisely if you add more information on the logic to your question...

Comment: The question shouldn't be closed since it has more interaction than the mentioned one.

Comment: Thank you @Corrl. I don't have permission to share my code in public, so I will figure out the solution.